# Is there a way to manually scroll a large image in PowerPoint?

Tags: image, scroll, powerpoint

[Preview of what I'm looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aL5dQ.png)

Hello, I'm looking for a way to manually scroll a large image in PowerPoint. In the image there's an example of what I'm looking for. I want to have a preview of the image that I can scroll through and the actual image that moves accordingly to the scrollbar.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want this in SlideShowView? For sure this can be achieved only by scripting. Essentially you would have to program buttons for up and down movements and use vba do apply this to the image. The preview is a bit more complicated since you would have to do some math too to achieve the conversion in the size differences. All in all a job for a programmer. Are you looking for programming support here?

Comment: Sure. I'm not familiar with VBA but I would be happy to receive any tips/ideas on how to do it. Also, would it be possible to drag the preview with your mouse instead of using up and down buttons?

Comment: @AntoineDescombes if you are not a programmer, this is the wrong place for you I fear. You might want to hire someone for that. You can not expect someone to write the whole code for you here. I gave you some pointers. Create Buttons and assign code for moving the image (by moving the shape's .top property. When it comes to dragging with the mouse this is way more complicated and I would not know how to approach that.